# Introduction to law

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does 'NO'in A citation stand for/mean

Pinchin and Another, NO v Santam Insurance Co. Ltd 1963 (2) SA 262 (W)

Comment: You might want to ask on the [Law SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/). Make sure to add where you found this (e.g. which country this refers to).

Answer (score 1):

This one was a really hard one to find. It seems peculiar to South African law citations / case law titles.

> Nomine Officio.

From the Case Citation Guidelines for Common Law Jurisdictions of the African Legal Information Institute:

> Individual Acting in an Official Capacity
>  An individual whose name
> appears in the decision’s heading merely because of his or her office
> in an organization or government body, does not act personally. Where
> a party appears in his official capacity, the letters NO follow his
> surname (stands for Nomine Officio)
>
> Eg. Bezuidenhout, Inspector General
> Becomes Bezuidenhout NO

[Manual](https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.africanlii.org%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2FMariya_Badeva_Case%2520Citation%2520Guidelines%2520for%2520Common%2520Law%2520Jurisdictions.docx)

So there are cases like:

Edelstein v Edelstein NO and Others
1952 (3) SA 1 (A) te 15

Clarke v Hurst NO 1992 (4) SA 630 (D).

Blesovsky NO and Others v Shipper and Another

Not to be confused with NO (number), No.2, etc.

These are all South African cases, including the one you gave in your question.

This is such an idiosyncratic notation from a particular country it's almost useless to know. You're better off knowing what the R in R v Brown stands for, or what Anor stands for in Hand v Morris and Anor.

It's so obscure I can't even find a definition for it separate from that style manual. Though it's similar to ex officio (by right of one's office)